# collapsible lists with *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, materialize

As it looks in the photo, that I want is, when I click show more, I want to expand this row, and show me all sensors in there

[image]

I'm using materialize, and my code html is:

```
    <table class="bordered table-bordered" [mfData]="homeboxsp | dataFilter : filterQuery" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="rowsOnPage"
        [(mfSortBy)]="sortBy" [(mfSortOrder)]="sortOrder">
        <thead style="color:black; background:rgb(207, 235, 245);border:1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190);">
          <tr>
            <th>
              <mfDefaultSorter by="client">Client</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
             <th>
              <mfDefaultSorter by="description">Homebox</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
 <th>
              <mfDefaultSorter by="sensors">Sensors</mfDefaultSorter>
            </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of homeboxsp">
            <td>{{item.client}}</td>
                <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                    <td>
              <ul>
                <ul *ngFor="let sensor of item.sensors">
                  <li>{{sensor.sensor_serial}}</li>
                </ul>
              </ul>
            </td>
                     </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Can you clarify: you want to expand the table row there?

Comment: Yes. When I click show more, I want to expand this row, and show me all sensors in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SlicePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) is perfect for this kind of situations. It does pretty much the same as the accepted answer with fewer *ngIf needed.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let val of values | slice:0:visible">{{val}}</div>
      <div *ngIf="visible==3" (click)="visible=values.length">show more</div>
      <div *ngIf="visible==values.length" (click)="visible=3">show less</div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  visible= 3;
  values = [1, 2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,9]
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

You can see a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/u8SIcbWNzGYKAth2GxYI?p=preview).

The same principle applies if you want to have multiple lists that expand. You just need to control the visibility for each list separately.

Here's an example of that.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div *ngFor="let group of groups">
        <div>{{group.name}}</div>
        <div *ngFor="let val of group.values | slice:0:(group.expanded? group.values.length :3)">{{val}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="!group.expanded" (click)="group.expanded=true">show more</div>
        <div *ngIf="group.expanded" (click)="group.expanded=false">show less</div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {

  groups = [{name: 'a', values: [1, 2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,9]},{name: 'b', values: [1, 2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,9]}]
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

And the working plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zj6igS43EZAWbm4pn7pg?p=preview).

Comment: Yes,thnx, this is good. But I have a problem when I have some rows.For example, when I click show more in row 1, in all rows show more sensor. How to select and visible all sensors in only one row? Thnx

Comment: Thank you very much! Works very well. :)

Answer (score 4):

you can do this in simple way using ngIf

```
<ul *ngFor="let sensor of item.sensors;let i = index;">
   <li *ngIf="i < value">{{sensor.sensor_serial}}</li>
   <button (click)="showmore()">showmore</button>
</ul>
```

ts

```
value:number = 2;

showmore(){
let value = this.value;
this.value= value+1;
}
```

you can modify logic as you want

Comment: this code, show me only one  sensor in all rows in every  click, not all sensors in one row when I click.

Comment: check updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kb6xxw?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a simple component that can show just a certain number of sensors, or adjust it to show just certain height:

```
<td><values-display-cmp [values]="row"></values-display-cmp></td>
```

Then the component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'values-display-cmp',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let val of shownValues">{{val}}</li>    
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="action" *ngIf="!open" (click)="more()">More</a>
  `

})
export class ValuesDisplayComponent {  
  @Input() set values(values) {
    this._values = values;
    this.shownValues = values.slice(0, 2);

  };
  open = false;
  shownValues = [];
  _values = [];

  more() {
    this.open = true;
    this.shownValues = this._values;
  }
}
```

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruuno7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) a full example.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your array in 2 parts, and after clicking `show more` concat them. Seems like not a big deal.